# Smuggler's trails - where can I find a tour?

Tags: tours

Are there places around the world that offer tours along the old smuggler's trails.  US-Mexico or US-Canada would be best but I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Doing a tour is usually the opposite of extreme tourism. Extreme would include Bear Grylls type things. Re-tagged for you! (-:

Comment: I don't know crossing on foot from Switzerland to France over the Alps sounds fairly extreme to me even though I may have a guide.

Comment: Well that would be tagging an answer rather than the question. If you're specifically only interested in routes comparable to crossing the Alps on foot then I recommend stating such in your question... otherwise consider revisiting **[Should tags reflect only the OP's question or the solution to the problem as well?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1035)**

Comment: @hippietrail I was using it as an example of an extreme.

Comment: So one example is extreme. Do you only want extreme answers? Tags should not be applied to a question just in case they might apply to some potential answers. Why not change your question to "Extreme smuggler's trails"?

Comment: @hippietrail I don't want to narrow down the question in that fashion.  Nor do I want to limit geographical location to North America

Comment: You just want to limit it to ones which are not out in the open? (-;

Comment: @hippietrail Basically not well known (which for smuggler's trails would probably be everything. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Smugglers used to have trails across the Swiss/French border in the alps. I just checked, and indeed there is someone offering a tour:

[Tour des Ruans - 
On the smugglers' path between France and Switzerland](http://www.alpineinterface.com/ruans/)

On the web, the tour organizer writes: *We will explain how smugglers and customs officials played a cat and mouse game during many years, and how France and Switzerland once went to battle in these very hills and 120 lives were lost.*

Also, as far as I know, there have been ancient smuggler's paths in the alps in the vicinity of the border crossing at [Saint-Gingolph, Lake Geneva](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=saint+gingolph&hl=de&ie=UTF8&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=44.25371,56.513672&t=m&hnear=Saint-Gingolph,+D%C3%A9partement+Haute-Savoie,+Rh%C3%B4ne-Alpes,+Frankreich&z=13). I am not talking about the WW2  smuggling activities mentioned in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Gingolph) about that town.